# iAd with Firemonkey?

Tags: ios, delphi, iad, firemonkey, fpc

I would like to know how (if?) I can put an iAd into an App created using Firemonkey. I have only been able to find one answer to this (in months of regular searching), which directed the poster to Apple's iAd documentation. I know how to use iAd in XCode, my question is how to use it with Firemonkey and FPC.

I've searched all the source code for iAd and related terms such as "bannerView" with no success. So I think my question is really how to import these classes into FPC.

Answer (score 1):

See Phil Hess' page for lots of information about ios SDK and FPC:

http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/

part3 discusses on how to build the iPhoneAll unit for the iOS simulator which enables you to use iAd functionality according to http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/iOS_Parsing_Status.html